# Las etiquetas [qrcode] y [qr] no tienen descripción y para colmo están en inglés

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Hoy les vengo a hablar de las etiquetas [qrcode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qrcode) y [qr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qr). Es correcto que existan, me parece bien, es una característica de algunos usos del lenguaje, es agnóstico del lenguaje (se usan en varios)...

El problema que veo es que deberían ser sinónimos entre sí y también deberían ser sinónimos de una etiqueta que no existe, y que debería existir que es [código-qr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%c3%b3digo-qr).

Lo pongo a consideracion de ustedes, ademas de que de crear ese tag (hay pocas preguntas con esos tags, facilmente en unos minutos se las puede pasar al nuevo tag), si las hacemos sinonimos, si las hacemos desaparecer, y si ademas, alguien sabe que deberia decir la descripcion.

Podriamos robar tranquilamente la que esta en ingles, que me parece correcta (no se si es la mejor)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece una propuesta totalmente coherente.

Comment: estoy de acuedo  que exista y que la etiqueta principal sea `QR-Code` como lo llama la [ISO](https://www.iso.org/standard/62021.html) que como saben todos su idioma oficial es en ingles

Comment: @JackNavaRow la iso define bar code (en otro caso) y nosotros tenemos la etiqueta codigo de barras.. no seria lo mismo en este caso? [tag:código-de-barras]

Comment: codigo de barras es [general](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_barras) @gbianchi

Comment: [un ejemplo de etiqueta en ingles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if) y no esta traducida

Comment: [tag:if] tampoco deberia existir ;) o vamos a tener una etiqueta por instruccion? y como traducirias if?

Comment: era un ejemplo @gbianchi de hecho hay una etiqueta else, ya quieren llenar la pagina como si fuera twitter o instagram